# gradle compile multipe source

Tags: java, gradle

This is straight from [Gradle 3.2.1 specifying_multiple_files](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:specifying_multiple_files). Why this does not work ? Why it cannot pick up files from `../shared/java` during compilation. Compilation fails for sources in  `src/main/java` depend on  `../shared/src`

The example is straight from Gradle

```
    task compile(type: JavaCompile)

    compile {
       // Add some source directories use String paths
       source 'src/main/java', 'src/main/groovy'

       // Add a source directory using a File object
       source file('../shared/java')

       // Add some source directories using a closure
       source { file('src/test/').listFiles() }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that page is written to show how you can work with files, but not necessarily how to configure the Java Compiler.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

That page will give you the details for what you are trying to solve.  What you need is to instead just define the sourceSet.

`sourceSets {
       main {
        java {
         srcDirs = ['src/main/java', '../shared/java']
        }
       }
    }`

Comment: The question is about JavaCompile and source. Any the page examples don't work for compile but yet they use words such as `compile` and the task compile. I think I am missing something to complete the example as the Gradle's own official page. Hence my question.

Comment: If you can get it to work with compile and source by adding remaining pieces of puzzle that will work for me. Optionally great if it also works with eclipse.